# Prolog: Move last element in list to front

Tags: prolog

Is there some built in predicate or easy way to move the last element in a list to the front? The only way I've come up with is a predicate that stores the last element, deletes it from the original list, and then doing `append(Last Elem, Original List, New List)` which is a bit cumbersome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if there are any built-in predicate, but this can be achieve with very simple code:

```
moveLast([], []).
moveLast(L, [H|T]) :- append(T, [H], L).
```

Comment: I don't think this will "move the last element in a list to the front".
`moveLast([1, 2, 3, 4], X).
X = [2, 3, 4, 1].`